# How to add permissions and configure links to a module in the /admin/modules page?

Tags: 8

I created a custom module and when I go to `/admin/modules` page it looks like this (no links):

[image]

How can I add the configure and permissions links to my custom module, just like Devel does?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure is the `configure` key in yourmodule.info.yml, containing a route name, usually your primary settings form/page.

Permissions link automatically shows by having permissions defined in your module.

Comment: Yes, there are feature checks in `ModulesListForm::buildRow` to see if help is installed and if the module has a `hook_help`.  Similar for permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code `configure: yourmodule.settings` in "yourmodule.info.yml" file.

meanwhile create a "yourmodule.routing.yml" file. place the below code in routing.yml file or make changes depends upon your needs.

`yourmodule.settings:
  path: 'admin/config/media/yourmodule'
  defaults: 
    _form: 'Drupal\yourmodule\Form\yourmoduleForm'
    _title: 'yourmodule Settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'`
you will get the configure link.